# Convert String to Date - Getting error

Tags: java, date, datetime

What would be the best way to convert String "**06 Nov 2013 17:43:07**" to joda DateTime / Date ? 
I am getting below error for my code

Code:

```
   DateTime publishTime = new DateTime((String)dataMap.getValue("publishDate"));
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "06 Nov 2013 17:43:07" is malformed     
at " Nov 2013 17:43:07"
      at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:747)
```

Is there a list of custom date formats we can pass to SimpleDateFormat constructor? Cannot find a consolidated list/link.

Thanks

Comment: The purpose of `SimpleDateFormat` is to allow you to build your own formats, so no, there's not an included list of common ones, unless you build them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Other than that Dateformats are well described here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks.. I used the custom date information you provided and used below code and not getting any error. Not sure if this approach is better than SimpleDateFormat but I also read SDF is not Thread safe. What do you suggest?

Comment: DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

DateTime publishTime = DateTime.parse((String)dataMap.getValue("publishDate"), fmt);

Date publishDate = publishTime.toDate();

Answer (score 1):

JodaTime's `DateTimeFormat` throws an exception if the month field doesn't match that of the default `Locale`. Try using `ENGLISH` Locale

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = 
   DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTime publishTime = DateTime.parse("06 Nov 2013 17:43:07", fmt);
Date publishDate = publishTime.toDate();
```